# Understanding the definition of "proper maps" in Differential Topology by Guillemin and Pollack

Tags: definition, differential-topology, intuition

I am trying to understand a piece of definition in *[Differential Topology](https://www.ams.org/books/chel/370/)* by Gullemin and Pllack (GP). 
Before introducing the concept of "embedding", GP gives the following definition (page 17):

> A map $f:X\to Y$ is called proper if the peimage of every compact set in $Y$ is compact in $X$. **Intuitively**, a proper map is one that maps points "near infinity" in $X$ to points "near infinity" in $Y$.

I do not understand the "intuition" part: what does it really mean (mathematically) and how does it relate to the definition of proper maps?

Comment: Hi, I put in my answer the way I can think of formalizing that intuitive idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compact sets are bounded in metric spaces. Assuming that our intuition of a compact set in a topological space is something that's not very large and we have some sort of control over its size compared to our space, the definition of a proper map says that the preimage of a compact set, i.e. something that is not very large, must be something that is not very large as well.

In a contrapositive sense, intuitively, that is like saying that if something is very large that its size gets out of hand, i.e. large enough to get close to infinity in some sense, then it must be mapped to something that is very large as well, i.e. "near infinity".

Comment: "In a contrapositive sense" basically answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: @user648097 I'm glad that it helped. You're welcome.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not agree with you. The definition of proper function is topological and not metric. In particular, its definition is not that preimage of bounded sets is bounded and in fact there exist non-proper continuous functions between bounded metric spaces. For example, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to the open $n$-ball $B^n$ so you can test your intuition with maps $B^n\to B^n$, conveniently with $n=2$, and you can check in this case that proper means that preimage of a subset that does not "touch" the boundary also holds this property

Comment: @DanteGrevino I never said that it has to be metric. I used the first sentence as a motivation for a more general concept for some intuition.

Comment: In this example, the disc, you can also find compact sets that have "size" (area) arbitrarily close to the area of the whole disc

Comment: @DanteGrevino I said "we have some sort of control over its size **compared** to our space". I didn't make any effort to make the notion of size rigorous here, neither do I intend to. The essence of my answer was to give intuition. Of course, you can always make any metric space bounded by changing the metric to $\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$. I don't see the relevance to be honest. I think we both agree that compact sets behave better than non-compact sets and non-rigorously speaking, very loosely-speaking, they're kind of finite and small compared to more pathological sets.

Comment: @DanteGrevino By the way, your answer is also very good and I totally love it. But one can also resort to non-Hausdorff examples and challenge it probably. And I'm sure non-Hausdorff spaces are of interest to algebraic geometricians. Forming an intuition about all topological spaces seems impossible to me. We always have to resort to the ones that are better understood and more familiar to us for motivation.

Comment: It is not my intention to fight, I simply do not agree with your interpretation essentially because it seeks metric intuitions for an eminently topological object. In my answer I speak of Hausdorff spaces (and, if you allow me, locally compact) because the phrase we try to decipher is from Guillemin and Polack's book, Differential Topology, and there we work with manifolds.

Comment: Regarding to arbitrary spaces, I feel in the depths of my heart that a function is proper if and only if for every pullback its opposite arrow is close. I said everything I wanted to say, but if you want to continue the talk, we could do it by chat. Anyway, I'm sorry for my fundamentalism.

Comment: @DanteGrevino I have no objection and I understand why you don't like my answer and I respect it. So, no hard feelings at all. I just think that you are changing the essence of my answer and interpret it in a way I didn't intend it to be taken.

Answer (score 7):

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous function between Hausdorff topological spaces. Let us consider the one-point Alexandroff compactifications $\overline{X}=X\cup\{\infty\}$ and $\overline{Y}=Y\cup\{\infty\}$. Then $f$ extends to a continuous function $\overline{f}:\overline{X}\to \overline{Y}$ such that $\overline{f}(\infty)=\infty$ if and only if $f$ is proper.